# How can I pin an Internet Explorer URL shortcut or favorite to the Start screen with Group Policy in Windows 8.1?

Tags: group-policy, windows-8.1

I created my Start UI like I want and used this PowerShell cmdlet to create the .xml file for a user's default layout:

*`export-startlayout –path <path><file name>.xml -as xml`*

(http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467928.aspx)

It created an `AppID` for each shortcut to a URL in the xml file.

Those `AppID`s are not consistent across machines (I tried it).

How can I add shortcuts to my Start UI in Windows 8.1 Pro with the layout xml file?

I put the xml file here.  It works great but no shortcuts.

```
*Administrative Templates / Start Menu and Task bar / Start Screen Layout*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my tests, the physical shortcut file needs to exist in the following path for it to display on the start screen:

%homeshare%\start menu\Programs\

Like you, I couldn't find a way of archiving this using "Export-startlayout".

Instead what I've done is put the shortcuts I want deployed in the GPT part of a GPO, I've then created a simply ROBOCOPY command to copy them to the start menu directory on login.

Example:

\domain.local\SysVol\tamar.local\Policies{F0C57572-7D16-49BC-8B4B-C8ABD9A363CB}\User\Scripts\Logon\ "%homeshare%\Start Menu\Programs" " webmail.url